# GLPK: Indexing variables with elements of a set

Tags: gnu, linear-programming, ampl, glpk

Let's say that I have a set and variables defined this way:

```
set Objectes;
var x{i in Objectes}>=0, integer;

s.t. rest: x[i in Objectes]>=7;


data;
set Objectes:= Animals Plantes Persones;
end;
```

I have 3 variables, let's say `x[Animals]`, `x[Plantes]` and `x[Persones]`. I want `x[Animals]` and `x[Plantes]` to be >=0, and `x[Persones]` to be >=7. I tried every logic way that came to my mind to define it on the "subject to" section, but it's not working. How I can do third variable <=7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it as follows:

```
s.t. rest: x['Persones'] >= 7;
```